# Number of Posts Edited - It doesn't get updated simultaneously

Tags: discussion, bug

[image: Posts Edited]

As you can see, the number of posts edited is different on both sides: First, just after the `Next badge` and second, on the right, how many posts edited. And it has been happening with me for a while. Even if you refresh the page, both numbers do not get the same value. But after some time - I'm not sure what time - they get synchronized. But it takes time, and it really shouldn't.

Comment: I suggest to post this in the [bug master list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253450/245360) on MSE.

Comment: You are right.  This error falls into a category of one-version-of-some-truth-does-not-match-another-version-of-that-truth, and there are thousands of them.  Although it has many online-database capabilities, and a few relational capabilities, the SO system is not an online relational database.  You are simply expecting too much of it.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: I don't think it is fair to say "you expect to much" if the correct number is 100 pixels away... It is clearly available and could be shown.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickHofman. They are too near to be different.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA any idea what is being used for database in SO

Comment: @Panther [SQL Server](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html), but it's also heavily cached.

Comment: @Panther.  Many years ago, when I tried to help them, it was SQL Server, heavily cached.  Now we have RAM in GB units, not MB units, so now the caching is 1,000 times what it was.  Doesn't help much.  Because the problem is not the cache, the problem is, the "database" is not a genuine database, it is a Record Filing system, with surrogates on every file, pre-1970 technology.  None of the integrity, power (all the expected features), or speed of a relational database.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman. We are discussing lack of an online database, and the evidence of that presented in the post, and you are talking Pixels ???

Comment: @PerformanceDBA I though it will be some NoSql Database like Hbase or most probably MangoDB

Comment: Indeed. Those square thingies on your screen you can't see any more. ;)

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Panther.  Those here-today-gone-tomorrow thingamijiggers (they don't known what they are) don't perform anywhere near a genuine Relational database deployed on a commercial (not freeware/shareware/vapourware) platform. The needs are straight relational, nothing fancy or new age.  Of course deploying a non-database on a database platform, and using a platform such as MS (which is hardly commercial) ... constitutes two massive architectural errors.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman. OMG, you mean the thing that is offending my sight, such that I can't see it any more.  Ok, got it, thanks!